# Integrate the following functions with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate the following functions with respect to $x$:

- $5x^4+3x+10$
- $x^3-2x^2+9x$

For context I have recently completed my university degree and decided to go over some first year mathematics only to find i'm really struggling to remember integration, these are two questions that I have written down but I am struggling to remember the method behind it. I post this question hoping someone would be able to do some form of step-by-step calculation.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.
Please use Wolfram alpha or other CAS for integral calculator.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Thank you for advice, edited to add context and implement MathJax

Comment: "Context" includes your own effort in solving your problem.  However, for simple questions which are a direct application of a formula, I don't think that's necessary.  Again you may consider using computer algebra system : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+5x%5E4%2B3x%2B10+with+respect+to+x for mechanical stuff

Comment: Think of integration as the inverse of differentiation. Derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ . Inversely, integral of $x^n$ is a function whose derivative equals $x^n$ . That function is $\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ .

Comment: @LukeNelson You've done a good job providing context to your question and so I've posted an answer. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the power rule?
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(ax^n)=anx^{n-1}
$$
I remember this rule using the mantra 'multiply by the power, subtract one from the power'. Since integration is differentiation in reverse, we have to 'add one to the power, divide by the power', so
$$
\int ax^n \, dx= \frac{ax^{n+1}}{n+1} + C\, .
$$
Use the power rule, along with the sum rule,
$$
\int f(x)+g(x) \, dx = \int f(x) \, dx + \int g(x) \, dx \, ,
$$
to solve your problem. You can write constants such as $10$ as $10x^{0}$.